# Bulk exporting of maps based on attribute table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, table, atlas

I have 73 locations that I have plotted in my attribute table, which I've labelled and can successfully create a map using Template Selector and then export this to a PDF for processing.

Is there a way to export every entry in the attribute table to a map without having to go through them one-by-one?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.14

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE! Make sure you take [the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), and try to follow the best practices for asking good questions. That way, you get good answers, and your question will be helpful to the next person. Always try to indicate in your question what you've tried so far to solve this problem yourself, so that other users can pinpoint where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: QGIS 3.0 has a reporting tool that you might find interesting to help you https://north-road.com/2018/01/23/exploring-reports-in-qgis-3-0-the-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the **Atlas Generator**. There are some [excellent](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html) [tutorials](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html) that cover this topic. Here's a brief overview.

In your Composer screen, you should see the **Atlas generation** tab in the sidebar. Check **Generate an atlas**, then select `your_layer` as the Coverage layer. Select `your_attribute` for the Page name. In the atlas toolbar, you can now turn on **Preview Atlas** (that's the far left button pictured below) and tab through the 73 features, each in their own map.

[image: atlas tab]

[image: atlas toolbar]

To make best use of the atlas tools, you'll need to use *atlas variables* in your composer screen, and possibly in your layer styling as well. For instance, a text box with your map's title would need to say something like `Map of [% @atlas_pagename %]` in order to update for each feature.

Additionally, under your map's **Item properties** tab, you may wish to select **Controlled by atlas** to automatically set the map position/scale relative to the individual feature.

[image: item properties tab]

When you're certain that your maps display to your liking, you can then bulk export your atlas as individual files, or even as a multi-page PDF.